# Multiple different calls to same activity issue

Tags: android

I have a simple application with which iam displaying weblinks in webviews.
i have two webViews one for links i want to open in portrait or in landscape

my code works well when i have only a single intent call and handling only one in the requested activity

now from my mainActivty i am sending the intent calls on the button click
here's the code

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button intra = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonIntra);
    intra.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent launchactivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    potraitWebview.class);
            launchactivity
                    .putExtra("QI",
                            "https://TEST.COM");
            launchactivity.putExtra("viewport", t);
            launchactivity.putExtra("overviewmode", t);

            startActivity(launchactivity);
            finish();
        }
    });

    Button chat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChat);
    chat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent launchactivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    potraitWebview.class);
            launchactivity.putExtra("chat",
                    "http://CHAT.COM");
            launchactivity.putExtra("viewport", t);
            launchactivity.putExtra("overviewmode", t);
            startActivity(launchactivity);
            finish();
        }
    });     

}
```

Now the activity i am calling im using this code to handle these requests and display the webpages

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.potraitlayout);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
            R.layout.customtitlebar);
    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewPotrait);

    // Handling incoming activity requests

    Bundle intraExtras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (intraExtras != null) {
        String value = intraExtras.getString("QI");
        viewport = intraExtras.getBoolean("viewport", false);
        overviewmode = intraExtras.getBoolean("overviewmode", false);
        url = value.trim();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value+" "+viewport+" "+overviewmode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }

    Bundle chat = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (chat != null) {
        String value = chat.getString("chat");
        viewport = chat.getBoolean("viewport", false);
        overviewmode = chat.getBoolean("overviewmode", false);
        url = value.trim();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value+" "+viewport+" "+overviewmode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
```

> *the issue here is **getIntent().getExtras();** which i am using if it is null for any of the activity requests which has not been currently
>   called the application crashes*

logcat

```
    05-02 11:33:49.153: E/AndroidRuntime(19950): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 11:33:49.153: E/AndroidRuntime(19950): Process: com.android.qintra, PID: 19950
05-02 11:33:49.153: E/AndroidRuntime(19950): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.qintra/com.android.qintra.potraitWebview}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 11:33:49.153: E/AndroidRuntime(19950):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
05-02 11:33:49.153: E/AndroidRuntime(19950):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
05-02 11:33:49.153: E/AndroidRuntime(19950):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
05-02 11:33:49.153: E/AndroidRuntime(19950):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
05-02 11:33:49.153: E/AndroidRuntime(19950):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-02 11:33:49.153: E/AndroidRuntime(19950):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-02 11:33:49.153: E/AndroidRuntime(19950):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
05-02 11:33:49.153: E/AndroidRuntime(19950):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 11:33:49.153: E/AndroidRuntime(19950):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-02 11:33:49.153: E/AndroidRuntime(19950):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
05-02 11:33:49.153: E/AndroidRuntime(19950):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
05-02 11:33:49.153: E/AndroidRuntime(19950):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 11:33:49.153: E/AndroidRuntime(19950): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 11:33:49.153: E/AndroidRuntime(19950):    at com.android.qintra.potraitWebview.onCreate(potraitWebview.java:54)
05-02 11:33:49.153: E/AndroidRuntime(19950):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
05-02 11:33:49.153: E/AndroidRuntime(19950):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
05-02 11:33:49.153: E/AndroidRuntime(19950):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
05-02 11:33:49.153: E/AndroidRuntime(19950):    ... 11 more
```

**line 54 is
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ctse.png**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  `if (intraExtras.containsKey("keyname"))` to check if bundle contains that key for which you are trying to fetch value.

```
if (intraExtras != null) {
    if (intraExtras.containsKey("QI")) {
        String value = intraExtras.getString("QI");
    }
    if (intraExtras.containsKey("viewport")) {
        viewport = intraExtras.getBoolean("viewport", false);
    }
    if (intraExtras.containsKey("overviewmode")) {
        overviewmode = intraExtras.getBoolean("overviewmode", false);
    }
    if (intraExtras.containsKey("chat")) {
        String value = intraExtras.getString("chat");
    }
}
```

Comment: ok will try that thanks
one basic doubt
getIntent().getExtras(); will capture all the calls right?
i dont have to make new bundle for every call?

Comment: @user3518278 Yes it will capture all calls.dont write it multiple times.If this answer solves your issue then accept this answer to close the questions.Cheers